# system() function doesn't produce expected output file

Tags: c, unix, graphviz

F
I'm using Graphviz to render .dot file as graphs, and typically I would write in my terminal :

`dot -Tpng yourFile.dot -o yourOutput.png` to produce a .png image representing my graph. (I'm using a Unix environment btw)

Now let's say I have the following C function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSIZE 255

typedef struct placeholder mystruct;

struct placeholder {
    ...
}

void outputGraph(mystruct str, char* outputName) {
    char command[MAXSIZE];
    char* tmpFile = "temp.dot";
    char imageFile[MAXSIZE];
    snprintf(imageFile, MAXSIZE, "%s.png", outputName);
    
    FILE* file = fopen(tmpFile, "w");

    writeStructToFile(str, file);

    snprintf(command, MAXSIZE, "dot -Tpng %s -o %s", tmpFile, imageFile);
    system(command);

    snprintf(command, MAXSIZE, "rm %s", tmpFile);
    system(command);
}
```

(my function WriteStructToFile is another one that I made and is working properly so the problem is somewhere else)

From what I understood about the `system()` function, it should produce the image output just the same as when I execute the same command myself.
Well, it does execute without any errors, but there is no image in the directory where I'm working.

At first, I thought, it's easy, `system()` doesn't start a new shell in the same working directory, so I tried to see the output of `system(pwd);` and it was my current working directory. So back to the starting point.

I also tried to check the value `system(command)` by doing `int status = system(command);` and then `printf("status : %d\n", status);` and, well, it printed `0`.

Now I'm kinda clueless, I really don't see why it doesn't produce the image output.
I'd be very interested in any ideas or even solutions you have.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of those `strcpy`/`strcat` calls you could use one single call to `sprintf`. You should check the length of your filenames before putting them into the buffer.

Comment: Did you verify that the correct string is created?

Comment: @Gerhardh Absolutely right for the `sprintf` I will definitely try with this one. Way cleaner.
Also yes, I checked and it is the exact same command I would write myself in the terminal, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: If I take your code with no changes and run it like `outputGraph("src.dot", "output.png")`, it Just Works: `dot` creates the file `output.png` as expected.

Comment: `snprintf()` is better than `sprintf()` here. And are you looking for the created file in the right directory?

Comment: @larsks I'm confused then, maybe I'm missing something and my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Shawn yes `snprintf` to care for the maximum number of bytes I want. And I think I'm looking the right directory because if I run `system(pwd)` it outputs my current directory so I think it'd be normal to expect the output file of the graph to be in the same directory as the .dot file right?

Comment: Your function definition — `void outputGraph(struct str, char* outputName) {` isn't valid.  You need either a structure tag or a variable name.  It's a little surprising if you're passing a structure rather than a structure pointer, but that's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've corrected by adding a typedef, I wasn't sure how to explain the thing without putting too much code for you too read.
Also I'm not passing a structure pointer because I don't really care about modifying the original structure and memory is not something I need to take care of here.

Comment: Is your dot file in your program's current working directory when you run it?

Comment: @Shawn Yes absolutely.

Comment: Please don't make your question a moving target by significantly changing the code.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm sorry, at first I didn't wanted to give too much code but I've understand that I need to give the proper information for you to be able to work with it. Also most of my edit were suggestions from others no more than that.

Comment: There is no need to provide the whole program. But the code must be as complete as needed to produce your problem. (I.e. you must provide a `main` function)  And it should be minimum to avoid reading unrelated stuff. If your initial code did not produce the error, it was wrong in first place. Please keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: If you want to adapt according to suggestions in comments, you can add this to your question. The initial code should still be there. Otherwise lots of comments become obsolete and might confuse future readers.

Comment: @Gerhardh Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant code, but it works & may help you debug your problem.  It calls **dot** in three different ways.  All three work as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   char command[50];
   int rc;
   
   strcpy(command, "dot -Tdot this.gv" );
   rc=system(command);
   printf("\n\n+++ call #1 returned %d\n", rc);
   strcpy(command, "dot -Tdot this.gv -oout1.dot" );
   rc=system(command);
   printf("\n\n+++ call #2 returned %d\n", rc);   
   strcpy(command, "dot -Tdot this.gv -o out2.dot" );
   rc=system(command);
   printf("\n\n+++ call #3 returned %d\n", rc);   
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, although I found the problem, I wasn't closing the file in which I was writing. Simple mistake so the `dot` command was actually executed without errors but since the file was empty it produced no graphs.

Answer (score -1):

```
snprintf(command, MAXSIZE, "touch %s", tmpFile);
system(command);
```

Why do you code that?

You certainly don't need to use [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) then [touch(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html).  You could use appropriate [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) ([open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [close(2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html)) here) or at least [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) followed by [fclose(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html).

You might in some cases consider using [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with [pclose(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html)

Of course, after

```
snprintf(command, MAXSIZE, "dot -Tpng %s -o %s", tmpFile, imageFile);
int bad = system(command);
```

You need to first check that `bad` is 0 and you probably want to use [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [access(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) to check that `imageFile` exists.

There could be many reasons why `system` with a `dot` command fails. For example, a bad `$PATH` variable. I suggest using  [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with [pclose(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html) and probably `/usr/bin/dot` in the command.

Compile your C code using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your executable. Both [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) could help you understand the behavior of your program.

Consider reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and studying for inspiration the source code of some simple open source Linux shells, such as [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or (more complex) [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Be aware that [Graphviz could be used as a library](http://graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf).

Comment: You're right, I even think that when I use `FILE* f = fopen("name", "w")` if the file doesn't exists then it's created, that would solve that part for sure, still doesn't help me with the whole Graphviz part :thinking_face:

Comment: But the main thing is, when I type myself in the terminal the exact string I give to the `system(string)` function, it works, but when it's executed by the function, it kinda works? Because there's no errors, but no output file either. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Also I'm already using `clang -Wall -Werror -Wextra -c` to compile, I think I won't have many more errors using gcc right?

Comment: You might get *different* warnings with `gcc`

Comment: I did it, no new errors, and same behavior as before, it executes without any errors, but doesn't produce an output file. I'm starting to wonder if it creates an output file somewhere in a mystery directory...

Comment: Did you use GDB?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't gave me hints of where the shady-stuff could be.

Comment: But GDB will tell you the *actual* commands passed to `system`

Comment: Perhaps I don't know how to use GDB the way you want me to. Because I definitely don't see the command passed to `system`

Comment: @SirHugo: Set a breakpoint on the line(s) containing `system()` calls and print the variable that you pass to `system()` — that is, `p command`.  Unless the output name is exceptionally long, you shouldn't be getting string truncation problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay! We're definitely getting somewhere, when I used `p command` before it printed this `dot -Tpng temp.dot -o image.png\000\a\000\000\000\000\000\000\000 \001\000\000\000\000\......` its basically end of string char repeating itself isn't it?

Comment: @SirHugo: That is probably OK — you're passing `system()` the string `"dot -Tpng temp.dot -o image.png"` with a null terminator (`\000`) and irrelevant garbage that won't be looked at.  Are the two file names what you expect to see?  Is `image.png` present in the directory after running that?  Have you checked that `temp.dot` contains what you expect?  Have you closed the file after the call to `writeStructToFile()` function?  What does `dot` do if the input file is empty?  Note that you should check that `fopen()` succeeds — every time.

Comment: These are indeed the two file names I expect to be there, the prog executes and ends without any problem, and yet `image.png` is no where to be seen in the current directoy after the end of the program... Okay I will everything else that you said too, and indeed I'm not closing the file...

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept my answer if it did help you

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't closing the `temp.dot` file in which I was writing. My mistake.
I shall now remember to always close files that I open!

A big thank you to everyone who helped on here.
(Whether it was for the problem or on how to use properly SO)